# "Perhaps, some bird lives in there" or "perhaps, a bird lives in there?"

Tags: indefinite-articles, modifiers

Imagine yourself walking in the woods with children. One child is saying, "there is a big hole in that tree's trunk." You answer, "perhaps a/some bird lives in there."

Would you use *a* or *some*? Please, elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use *a* in this sentence, but you could use either.

One of the meanings of *some* is:

> **some** *2* used to refer to someone or something that is unknown or unspecified : *she married some newspaper magnate twice her age* | *there must be some mistake* | *he's in some kind of trouble*.

So to refer to "some bird" living in a tree trunk simply means it is an unknown or unspecified bird, if it does in fact exist. But the indefinite article accomplishes the same task, and does so with a single letter, so I would prefer it in this case.

Comment: If someone said to me, "Some bird lives there", I think I'd be more likely to interpret it with the slang meaning of "bird" ("woman")... I suspect this is a British thing.

Comment: @psmears - Is it like "this bird has flown" in "Norwegian wood" by the Beatles?

Comment: @psmears: You know a lot of women who live in holes in trees, do you? :) Anyway, you're right that "bird" is a British slang synonym for *woman*. @brilliant: Yes, John Lennon was making a pun on the dual meanings of "bird" in that song.

Comment: @Robusto: What company I keep is my own business :-P (But my point is that the association is so strong that, even in that context, if a native speaker said "some bird lives there" then [this](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/YX_vR4gMnDnpTGWVIgbu0w) would indeed be the sort of picture that came to mind... Saying "a bird" avoids this issue.)

Comment: I think there are slightly perjorative overtones to using *some* instead of *a* in this context. Which might explain why some of us are more inclined to interpret "bird" in the correspondingly perjorative sense.

Comment: @psmears: Well, if I were to see an underage girl like the one in your picture, I doubt I would refer to her by any term that might have sexual connotations. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've always understood "bird" to be used the way Americans would use "chick" — as descrbing someone who might possibly be the target of sexual interest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, definitely!

Comment: @Robusto: It *can* be used that way, but these days largely it's used as a general purpose slightly-disparaging word for "woman", with no particular sexual connotation attached. It would probably be unusual to use it for such a young girl, but alas there's a limit to how much time I can afford to spend searching the internet for pictures of nubile girls standing by trees in order to further your education :)